# invalid_grant Error when Authenticating oauth Request - Google Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, oauth-2.0

I am attempting to get access to a customer's Google Drive to download their files. When testing the code on my own google drive, I am able to successfully download files. However, when I get the oauth code from them, I get the error:

```
oauth2client.client.FlowExchangeError: invalid_grant
```

After looking at some of the other answers, it has been suggested that you ensure access_type='offline', which seems to be the default and I can see in the generated url that this parameter is set. It also sounds like the code they give back may only be valid for an hour, however I have tried to use it within the hour and still no luck. Any other suggestions for how to avoid this problem?

Here is the code I have been running:

```
from oauth2client import client
import webbrowser

flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
  'client_secrets.json',
  scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
  redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')

auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
webbrowser.open(auth_uri)

print auth_uri

auth_code = raw_input('Enter the auth code: ')

credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
```

It errors on the flow.step2_exchange line.

Answer (score 1):

There are three standard causes for this error that I am aware of.

1. The time is off on your PC. **Solution**: check it.
2. You are trying to use an authentication code more then once.
   You can only use the authentication code once to get the refresh token.
3. You are testing and authenticating the code more then once. Each time you authenticate the code you get a valid refresh token.  You can get up to 25 refresh tokens and then they stop working.  **Solution**: make sure that every time you refresh the access you are using that refresh token and not an older one.

Also google as a Python tutorial that shows you how to access drive using the Python Client library it may make things easer for you.   [Python QuickStart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It seems that the token is valid if I use it within 15 minutes of the user allowing access. I checked the time on my PC and it is in sync with NTP. I'm not using a token more than once, and I'm only using one at a time. I'm unsure on why the time limit seems to be impacting the token, but for now my problem is resolved (I just have to make sure to use the token fast). If you have any other thoughts on why it's behaving as it is, I'd be interested to hear them!

Comment: Which token is it that you are talking about? If its the authentication code yes you need to use that ASAP and get your access token and refresh token back.   Its not going to hang around for long.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, the authentication code. Didn't realize there was a time limit. Do you know how long it is? This made it challenging when trying to coordinate with someone else to get the code.

Comment: No Idea how long you have to exchange an authentication code its not long.  defiantly under 15 minutes.   Shouldn't be to hard to write a script to test it